# Android Studio: disable warning "if statement can be simplified"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Android studio marks warnings in Java code, some of them I consider useless and want to disable them. 
I know I can configure Inspections that are enabled, but for some of these I can't find where it can be disabled. Then code is marked to have issues, and I want to have clean code so that I see real problems.
Example of warning:

```
'if' statement can be replaced with 'return ...'
```

[image]

And I don't want to put annotations to my code, rather I'd like to switch this off in IDE.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you click on the lightbulb and then on the suggested action's arrow, you get submenu with options. First one should be "Edit inspection profile setting", which should navigate you to the exact place in Settings, where you can edit given inspection.

---

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is a more general answer for future viewers. These are various ways to suppress the warning.

## Statement

Add the following comment above the line with the `if` statement.

```
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (...)
```

## Method

Add the following line at the beginning of the method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("SimplifiableIfStatement")
private boolean myIfMethod() {
    if (...) return false;
    return (...);
}
```

## Class

Add the following line at the beginning of the class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("SimplifiableIfStatement")
public class MyClass { ... }
```

## Current project

Position your cursor on the `if` statement and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then choose **Simplify > Disable inspection**.

[image]

## All projects

Position your cursor on the `if` statement and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then choose

[image]

## Reapplying the inspection

If you disabled the inspection by mistake, you can turn it on again.

1. Go to **File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > J2ME issues**
2. Check the line for "*if statement may be replaced with && or || expression*"

## Notes

- The inspection is there for a purpose. It would generally be better to follow the warnings advice and just simplify the `if` statement. (However, sometimes I find the "simplification" harder to read. Thus my answer here.)
- You don't really need answers like this. You can autogenerate the suppression code for any warning by clicking on the code with the warning and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then expanding the options the lightbulb. You will be given options to suppress the warning for the statement, method, class, etc.

Comment: This answer is correct for above question. I only wanted to notice that sometimes errors resulting from if statements need to be suppressed with "RedundantIfStatement". In these cases "SimplifiableIfStatement" does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Java -> Control flow issues -> Redundant 'if' statement

You can type "if statement" in the search box to highlight all inspections involving `if`.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 3.4.1 at least, if you right click on the Analysis marker at top right of the code pane you can change the level of highlighting there.  I've set my level to 'Syntax only'.